# json format as parameter for cordova or phonegap ios plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating a phonegap plugin for ios my question is instead of the usual "string" parameter can i pass a json format parameter?

Every tutorials i've found uses string as a parameter. How would i do it if i will use a json format variable as parameter to my plugin? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare the JSON-Data, before passing it to Cordova.exec use `JSON.stringify`

```
PhoneGap.exec('Alarm.update',JSON.stringify(list));
```

Maybe this could help you:[PhoneGap exec passing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993410/phonegap-exec-passing-objects-between-js-and-obj-c)

Answer (score 0):

In current version, Object passed in Javascript can be read:

```
JSONObject params = args.getJSONObject(0);
```